# Quoting parameters in to_csv and pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

TLDR; I **want** each item to be wrapped in quotes. When I wrap it in quotes in Jupyter Notebook it has double quotes but when I open it as a file manually (opens in Pages or Excel) it doesn't show double quotes. I'm unsure if I'm going crazy or if these files actually have double quotes

### Sample Dataset:

| pizza_topping_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| "1" | "junglehouse1@yahoo.com" |

I run this to read it in into Jupyter Notebook:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/test_file.csv', dtype=str, na_values='')
```

It loses it's quotations when I read in the CSV without the quoting parameter. So I then run the following:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/test_file.csv', dtype=str, quoting = 3, na_values='')
```

This shows the csv to have double quotes.

I want to save this as a CSV now:

```
df.to_csv('~/Downloads/TEST_QUOTE_TEST.csv', header=True, index=False,quoting=3, line_terminator='\r\n')
```

I open it manually and this doesn't show the double quotes I had added to my CSV in Jupyter Notebook. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible you are just missing that it worked? My variant of your save to csv command seems to work. My example of the saving the dataframe as csv after starting with your sample input (which you could have provided as text ?!): `df.to_csv('TEST.csv', header=True, index=False,quoting=3)` . However, looking at it in the CSVTable view in JupyterLab hides them. I needed to open it with the text editor in JupyterLab by right-clicking on the file in the file browser to see the items still quoted. In the classic interface it opens in the Text Editor by default and shows the quotes.

Comment: Oh yes, there is your problem probably: " but when I open it as a file manually (opens in Pages or Excel)  ". They probably hide them like the CSVTable viewer in JupyterLab. You need to open it with a text editor on your machine. Use Visual Studio Code or SublimeText on your local machine and you should see the quotes are there. The rendering you get in Excel or Pages isn't the true view, at least I suspect that is the issue you are missing.

Comment: By the way, if you want to try JupyterLab without installing it, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and click 'launch binder'. In the session that comes up, from the JupyterLab interface you can then switch to the classic interface  from under the 'Help' menu that is along the top of the page.

Comment: Ah got it Wayne thanks! looks like I do have to open it with a text editor! How do I make your comment the key answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your problem probably:

> "but when I open it as a file manually (opens in Pages or Excel) ". Those viewers probably hide them like the CSVTable viewer in JupyterLab.

You'll need to open your CSV file (or for that matter, any text-based file or code) with a text editor on your machine **to always examine the true state**.
Use Visual Studio Code or SublimeText on your local machine and you should see the quotes are there since my slight adaptation of your code worked in my Jupyter session.